# Routing rules for subdomain functionality using Node.js & npm/connect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following Node.js server side code:

```
  var connect = require('connect');
  connect.createServer(
  connect.static(__dirname)
  ).listen(8080);
```

I use this simple peace of code to have my localhost running on Node.js. Moving the connect package and that server side
code get's my server running directly on the webapp which I find practical. I would like to extend this to have subdomain 
functionality. 
When I place the address

localhost:8080/companyA I want the link:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

to be redirected to:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="companyA/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

in other words I want my resource folder where I keep company styles to be variable and based on the subdomain. Only this
folder should be dynamic the other folders should be the same, e.g., I want my index.html to be the same across subdomains.

Can anyone explain/guide me through steps to achieve this or give me some guidance for someone that knows how to code but 
is quite new on server side code and Node.js.

Comment: There may be a reason to have this within your application, and this is a perfectly good question.  However, this sort of need is usually addressed by a web server such as Nginx.  It's best to leave static file serving and basic redirection like this up to a native server, for better performance, unless your application has a need to do something with these resources as they are served.